# ScriptManager in Master page and Content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question about Scriptmanager, my question is:
I need in master page a ScriptManager for this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManger1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

and I need in my content page a ScriptManager because if I remove from here when I run my application give me a error because I need a ScriptManager and if I put a ScripManager when I run my application give me a error because I have 2 ScriptManager because I have 1 in master page and 1 in content page.

My question is How I fix this?

Comment: What exactly are the errors you are getting?

Comment: where is the tag here, please mark it¿?

Answer (score 13):

You are right that you can have only 1 ScriptManager. This should most definitely go in your master page. To get ScriptManager functionality in your other pages, you will need to use a ScriptManagerProxy. Think of this proxy as forklifting all requests made to it to the real ScriptManager loaded in the master page.

Toss this little guy in your other pages:

```
 <asp:ScriptManagerProxy id="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server"/>
```

Here is a good read on how to apply this in more detail:

http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/ajax-package-scriptmanagerproxy-control-in-asp.net-using-vb.1